# 100k linear potentiometer with arduino

Tags: arduino, current, potentiometer

Is it OK if I use 100K linear potentiometers to input values to Arduino?

The documentation specifies [10K](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial) should be used and I suppose that would translate to 0.5mA power consumption which would be well within spec of maximal 40mA per pin.

The question is, would it be fine to use 1K or 100K potentiometers because that should translate to 5mA and 0.05mA power consumption?

What is the advantage/disadvantage of using higher or lower value potentiometers?

What are the upper/lower values pots which are OK to use?

Comment: 40mA refers to the pin used as an output. It's got nothing to do with using the pin as an input. The lower limit on a pot depends (a) on what's driving it and (b) where the pot burns out. The upper limit comes from the maximum recommended source impedance for an ADC input, which will be in teh CPU's datasheet.

Comment: Yes, the 5V pin on Arduino is used as output and that's why I mentioned 40mA. It's the setup I linked in my question and the pot goes from 0 to 100K in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Brian Drummond suggested, when you set the pins to input mode, they have high impedance, so they're not going to sink much current no matter how the external resistors are set up. The data sheet suggests using 10k or less because if you use a higher value than that, you'll need to increase the sample time of the ADC. The ADC works by allowing current from the input to charge a capacitor, then holding the the charge in the capacitor and using it as the input to a comparator. The ADC repeatedly generates candidate values and compares them with the capacitor charge until it finds the closest match; that value becomes the ADC output. If the impedance of the analog source is greater than 10k, the capacitor won't fully charge, and you'll get incorrect readings. You can increase the sample time, but that will decrease your sampling resolution (you'll get fewer samples per second). I don't think there's much reason to use a 100k pot over a 10k unless 100k is all you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I have mostly 100K pots and a 1K pot. How inaccurate should would the reading be with 100K pots? What would be the downside of using 1K or lower pots?

Comment: I don't know how inaccurate the reading would be with the 100k pot. Just grab your multimeter and give it a try. If it's not accurate enough, you can slow down the ADC, but in order to do that, you'll need to leave the confines of the Arduino environment, because Arduino library configures the ADC to use a 125kHz clock. Probably easier just to get a 10k pot or use the 1k pot, which will probably work just fine.